# MySQL Update if value is x or y

Tags: mysql

I have following procedures which help me to update the dates in my table on a daily basis, keeping them relevant for demo purposes. The difference between those two procedures is only that they are being executed for 2 different clients with `property_id` being `2` and `3` respectively.

```
UPDATE `opera_pms_detail` SET `arrival` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 2), `departure` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 1), `read_on` = NULL WHERE `property_id` = 2 AND `import_type` = '1'

UPDATE `opera_pms_detail` SET `arrival` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 2), `departure` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 1), `read_on` = NULL WHERE `property_id` = 3 AND `import_type` = '1'
```

Now, for efficiency's sake, is there a better way of doing this? Instead of having to call the procedure twice, can I just update the columns for both clients in one call?

Thank you

Comment: Like ..WHERE property_id IN (2,3).. or ..WHERE (property_id = 2 OR property_id = 3).. ?

Comment: Right, time for bed... Thanks for helping with this and thank you for making me feel stupid. Night.

Comment: Yes . Store the date, not the duration

Answer (score -1):

Try implementing your procedure like this

```
PROCEDURE ýour_procedure_name(IN p_property_id INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE `opera_pms_detail` 
SET `arrival` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 2),
`departure` = SUBDATE(curdate(), 1),
`read_on` = NULL 
WHERE `property_id` = p_property_id 
AND `import_type` = '1';
END
```

And you will call your procedure as:

```
CALL `your_procedure_name`(property_id)
```

Comment: And how does this approach may solve OP's task "Instead of having to call the procedure twice, can I just update the columns for both clients **in one call**?"

Comment: It does not seem very useful. You may want to run the procedure with three, four, and so on clients, in which case, you may add a cursor to your procedure based on a clients table, an a prepare statement inside a loop.

Comment: OP do **NOT** want multiple calls! He wants one single call.

Comment: You may run the Update query modifying the where clause as: "where (property_id = 3 or property_id = 3) and import_type = '1'"